# How to pass the input entered in an html form to the action of the same form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<form action="<c:url value = "/deal/#value-that-user-enters#"/>" method="POST">
Kindly enter the deal id : <input type="text" name="dealId">
<input type="submit" value="Get the deal" />
</form>
```

In the above code, I want the action attribute of form to be /deal/(deal-id-entered-by-user). Is there any way to do it without using any javascript? And is it at all possible even with javascript?

Comment: You have to use JavaScript to do this.

Comment: What language is `<c:url `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it simply with javascript like this:

```js
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function() {
  this.setAttribute('action', "/baseurl/" + document.querySelector('input[name=dealId]').value)
}
```

```html
<form action="/baseurl/" method="POST">
  Kindly enter the deal id :
  <input type="text" name="dealId">
  <input type="submit" value="Get the deal" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to change the form action by javascript:

```
document.forms[0].action=documnet.getElementById('dealId').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
<form action="<c:url value = "/deal/#value-that-user-enters#"/>" method="POST">
Kindly enter the deal id : <input type="text" class="myBox" name="dealId">
<input type="submit" value="Get the deal" />
</form>


$('.myBox').on('change', function (event) {
    var myVal = $(this).val();
    $('form').attr('action', function(i, value) {
        return value + myVal;
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see the question tagged with jQuery.

Comment: Why are you attempting to edit the question to include the jQuery tag? Do you know that the user wants to use it?

Comment: @j08691   I am just suggesting him to use jquery. If he is not comfortable with it. he will discard my edit. I am not forcing to edit his/her question. Did you get it?

Comment: No, by editing the question it joins the other questions with suggested edits where SO members with enough rep can vote on it. You're not simply notifying the OP to accept the edit.

Comment: I have tagged javascript though. I dont see why jquery is essential when some primitive js code snippet does the work. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: The issue is that it makes no sense to include an entire library for one line of code, especially when the question suggests that even using javascript to do it is undesirable if it can be avoided somehow